# List of eigenvalues for the Schrödinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm writing an algorithm which computes the eigenvalues $E$ of the Schrödinger equation with potential $V(x) = x^2$, ie the harmonic oscillator. The equation is defined as follows

$$
y''(x) = (E-x^2)y(x) \, \, \text{where } x \in [-10, 10]
$$

together with some boundary conditions, $y(-10) = y(10) = 0$. But how can I know if the output (the computed values $E$) is correct, or in other words, is there a list where I can find some of these $E$ values?

Comment: [This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02724052) (paywalled unfortunately) may be of some help.